# Printing checks from Usb thermal printer don't work in some devices and version android/sdk

Tags: android, flutter, printing, usb, thermal-printer

I use [flutter_usb_printer](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_usb_printer) library for printing checks on usb thermal printer.
On some devices it's work, but on Google pixel 3 with android version 12 and on Google pixel 4 with android version 13, it's don't work.

Who can help me?
Maybe i must be use another library. Or who know how it's can fix?

When i connect my usb thermal printer, device ask me about permission for using usb printer, and when i agree, device locked and unlocked, but thermal printer don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android\app\build.gradle`
set `targetSdkVersion` to under 31 to fix your error

```
defaultConfig {
   targetSdkVersion 30
}
```

Comment: It's not work.
I'm already using targetSdkVersion 31.

Comment: please using targetSdkVersion 30

Comment: yes it's work, but if my app is release in play market and i use targetSdkVersion 31, can i change this value?